# Rails prints string when each is used in html.erb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, string, each, erb

While it could of course be done neater by putting the code into the controller or something, I can not image why the following is happening:
assume that `@some_table.some_text` contains 5 lines.
putting the following code in my html.erb file:

```
<% @some_table.some_text.lines.each do |cur_line| %>
    foo
<% end %>
```

results in 5 `foo`s followed by all the lines in `@some_table.some_text`.
I could imagine this would happen when using the `<%= %>` but not with `<% %>`.
Obviously, I don't want the `@some_table.some_text` to be shown.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's just the way that the Ruby `lines` method works - it returns an Enumerable, which can't be looped through in the same way. For your purposes, try

```
<% @some_table.some_text.split(/\n/).each do |cur_line| %>
```

instead.

Alternatively convert the Enemerable into an array before calling `each`, using one of the [methods](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Enumerable.html), eg:

```
<% @some_table.some_text.lines.collect.each do |cur_line| %>
```

Comment: Thanks, that works. It still confuses me though, I thought `<% %>` was not supposed to render any returning data as html output.